# How to set routes.php for change my url in CodeIgniter?

Tags: url, routes

I have to change www.sample.com/welcome/aboutus to www.sample.com/aboutus , but when I go to www.sample.com/aboutus it displays a `404 error` page. I've tried to route, but I can't get this to work.

I tried this one in config/routes.php page,

```
$route['welcome/aboutus'] = 'aboutus';
```

and this is my header page code,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/aboutus');?>">About Us</a>
```

please help me to fix this issue.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes I did it.this is the right way.I was change my config/routes.php page

```
$route['aboutus'] = 'welcome/aboutus';
```

and I changed my header page,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('aboutus');?>">About Us</a>
```

I think this is the right way.